# Undefined method `mass_assignment_sanitizer=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm learning Rails with the awesome *Ruby on Rails Tutorial* by Michael Hartl. I'm on [section 3.2.2 (Test Driven Development)](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#fnref:3.14) in which I need to run the following command to run the rspec tests for my Rails project:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/
```

But it doesn't work. Instead I get this error:

```
/Users/mh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing':
undefined method `mass_assignment_sanitizer=' for
ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I've tried reinstalling `rspec` and [changing my Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/1524307), but nothing appeases the undefined method error!

Comment: Oh, also, when I try to run `rspec spec/` I get a `command not found` error.

Comment: try without trailing slash. `rspec spec`. (*just thinking*)

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error without the slash.

Comment: What if you put config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict in config/enviroments/test.rb? Are you using rails2?

Comment: I'm using rails 3.1. I added the line of code but still get the error.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Did you downgrade from Rails 3.2 RC1? Comment out the following two lines from your development.rb:

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me after downgrading from 3.2 to 3.1.2!

Comment: since TS using rspec , he should be commenting out the line in test.rb instead of development.rb

Comment: Had this same problem and fix when upgrading from Rails 3.2 to 4.2

Answer (score 1):

While m818's answer will solve the problem, you might still get errors if you are tyring to use deprecated methods elsewhere in your code.

I had the same problem, commenting out those lines got rid of some errors, but not all of them, anywhere I was using `attr_accessible` gave me the same error.

It turned out to be the `active_record' gem that was updated to 4.0 when I didn't want it to. Since I'm using a Padrino app, I had to do this in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord', '= 3.2.12', :require => "active_record"
```

That solved all issues and I didn't have to comment out the lines in `database.rb`.