# Why do I get an "undefined method `mass_assignment_sanitizer='" error?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working with Rails 3.1.3 on Windows 7.

I'm getting the following error when creating a new model:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb 
:1088:in `method_missing': 
undefined method `mass_assignment_sanitizer=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class(NoMethodError)
```

My gem file is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

When I run the `bundle` command, it executes without a error.

I also tried modifying my Gemfile like:

```
gem 'rails' ,'3.1.0'
```

and with:

```
gem 'rails' ,:git => 'git@github.com:rails/rails.git'
```

But it gives me the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647053/undefined-method-error-when-running-rails-bundle-exec-rspec-command

Comment: Thanks for pointing that.. but I think its little different as:
I can run my each spec,
My local rails s command works fine.

The only thing that is not working is generate command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install rails 3.2

```
gem install rails --pre
```

And add mysql gem to your bundle and run

```
bundle install
```

Then try to create models and run your test cases.

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3.1, you should probably use the `mysql2` gem if you have a **MySQL** database, and you probably do not need the `sqlite3` gem. Do you use a **SQLite** or **MySQL** database? If you use **SQLite**, then you probably do not need the `mysql` or `mysql2` gem. Maybe a gem problem?

Comment: ok, I guess we can rule that out. Maybe a problem with Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.1.