# I am getting error while installing spree ? undefined method `mass_assignment_sanitizer=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: spree

ptsadmin@ptsadmin-desktop:~/swaptan/26March/my_store$ rails g spree_news:install
/home/ptsadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing': undefined method`mass_assignment_sanitizer=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 2):

Edit Development.rb
and comment these 2 lines

config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct version of the `active_record` gem, presumabely 3.2.12, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647053/undefined-method-error-when-running-rails-bundle-exec-rspec-command/19006797#19006797) for further info.