# Omniauth to login through Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, omniauth

i am developing a rails application, which allows users to login through twitter and they can tweet and search. previously for some other application i used omniauth to login through twitter it worked fine(rails 3.1.3)(full log https://gist.github.com/2423973). but in this application i am getting the following error when i go to localhost:3000

undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass(full log https://gist.github.com/2423983)

this app is using

rails 3.2.1
omniauth 0.2.6

i tried switching back to the rails 3.1.3 version but ended up with different error

/home/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@twitterapp/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing': undefined method`mass_assignment_sanitizer=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

so where exactly is the problem?

Comment: where did you use this `mass_assignment_sanitizer=` ? in your code

Comment: If you are going back to an older version of rails you need to make sure your application.rb is compatible, maybe create a new rails 3.1.3 app and reference that

Comment: @uDaY: i didn't use it any where..

Comment: @house9: what about rails 3.2.1? cant i use omniauth with this?

Comment: @santosh, dude try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647053/undefined-method-error-when-running-rails-bundle-exec-rspec-command hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

[Sample source code](https://github.com/mohitjain/social-login-in-rails) which integrates with all the popular social networks ie Devise + Twitter + Facebook + Linkedin + Google + Github

*Disclaimer: I wrote that application. In case you are facing any issues. Feel free to ping me on stackoverflow or open an issue on github.*